# How to create a custom Serializer for Ember data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have an API that returns JSON that is not properly formatted for Ember's consumption.
Instead of this (what ember is expecting):

```
{ events: [
    { id: 1, title: "Event 1", description: "Learn Ember" },
    { id: 2, title: "Event 2", description: "Learn Ember 2" }
]}
```

I get:

```
{ events: [
    { event: { id: 1, "Event 1", description: "Learn Ember" }},
    { event: { id: 2, "Event 2", description: "Learn Ember 2" }}
]}
```

So if I understood correctly, I need to create a custom Serializer to modify the JSON.

```
var store = DS.Store.create({
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
        serializer: DS.Serializer.create({
            // which hook should I override??
        })
    })
});
```

I've read the code comment related to the DS.Serializer, but I can't understand how to achieve what I want...

How can I do it?

ps: My goal is to make `App.Event.find()` work. Currently, I get `Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key 0 but you have no mapping for it`. That's why I need to fix the JSON received.

**edit**: Here's how I made it work, for now:

```
extractMany: function(loader, json, type, records) {
    var root = this.rootForType(type),
    roots = this.pluralize(root);

    json = reformatJSON(root, roots, json);
    this._super(loader, json, type, records);
  }
```

Comment: What version of Ember Data were you using here?

Comment: `CURRENT_API_REVISION: 4`, if that helps...

Comment: FWIW, this is a very old and outdated version of Ember Data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am assuming that the responses contain the IDs only, and that you are trying to extract them.

You will want to subclass `DS.JSONSerializer`, which supplies the basic behavior for dealing with JSON payloads. In particular, you will want to override the `extractHasMany` hook:

```
// elsewhere in your file
function singularize(key) {
  // remove the trailing `s`. You might want to store a hash of
  // plural->singular if you deal with names that don't follow
  // this pattern
  return key.substr(0, key.length - 1);
}

DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  extractHasMany: function(type, hash, key) {
    return hash[key][singularize(key)].id;
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my post with additional info. `extractHasMany` is never called, `extractMany` is. My goal is just to make `App.Event.find()` work right now. I managed to make it work by overriding `extractMany` and just modifying the json by hand to make it fit the requirement (`{ events: [ {}, {} ] }`)...

Comment: I assume you're calling `this._super` after munging the data?

Comment: Indeed. I updated my answer. But I wonder if there isn't a better way to do that. It will do for now, and if I realize I have to override too many methods, then I can think about improving it. Thanks.