# Laravel 4 Collections and Ember-DATA JSON

Tags: ember.js, laravel, ember-data, laravel-4

Ember's RESTAdapter expects JSON responses to be organized a bit differently than L4 Eloquent's default collection.

From the Ember Guide:

```
{
  "post": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Rails is omakase",
    "comment_ids": [1, 2, 3]
  },

  "comments": [{
    "id": 1,
    "body": "But is it _lightweight_ omakase?"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "body": "I for one welcome our new omakase overlords"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "body": "Put me on the fast track to a delicious dinner"
  }]
}
```

Is there a way to get Ember to map to L4 collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to overwrite the serializer in order to support laravel's json format.

See:

- [How to create a custom Serializer for Ember data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300679/how-to-create-a-custom-serializer-for-ember-data)
- [Unable to get hasMany association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170370/unable-to-get-hasmany-association/14171947#14171947)

Hope it helps.