# Implementing custom ajax calls when loading data in model

Tags: ember.js

In my Emberjs application I have an Employee model which I should load through a REST Get API call, where I have to authenticate the API first for a token then start loading the data, I know how to do this easily using JQuery but not sure how I can implement this in EmberJS, so I will appreciate it so much if anyone can instruct me how to do so.

Below is the JQuery code I use for authentication, extracting the employees data, as well as my EmberJS model code

Thanks

Authentication:

> ```
>  $.ajax
>   ({
>     type: "POST",
>     url: "http://portal.domainname.com/auth",
>     dataType: 'json',
>     async: false,
>     data: JSON.stringify({ 
>         Login: "logmein@email.com", 
>         Password : "test"
>     }),
>     success: function(data) {
>         console.log(data); //Here I get the token needed for further calls...
>     },
>     error: function(xhr, error){
>         console.debug(xhr); console.debug(error);
>     } 
> });
> ```

Calls to load employees data:

> ```
> $.ajax   ({
>     type: "GET",
>     url: "http://portal.domainname.com/employees",
>     dataType: 'json',
>     async: false,
>     beforeSend: function (xhr) {
>         xhr.setRequestHeader ("Token", "0000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000");
>     },
>     success: function(data) {
>         console.log(data);
>     },
>     error: function(xhr, error){
>         console.debug(xhr); console.debug(error);
>     }  });
> ```

EmberJS Model

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11
});

App.Employee = DS.Model.extend({
  employeeID:             DS.attr('string'),
  employeeName:        DS.attr('string')
});

App.Store.reopen({
 adapter: 'DS.RESTAdapter'
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add headers to all Ember AJAX requests like this:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 13,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
      if (!hash) {
        hash = {};
      }
      hash.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token " + window.sessionToken);
      };
      return this._super(url, type, hash);
    }
  })
});
```

I use this code in production.

Answer (score 1):

A very real & viable solution is to avoid using EmberData and just use ajax the way you already know. Take a look at this tutorial from a founder of Discourse (which uses Ember without Ember Data):

http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html

Answer (score 0):

As a hack you could use something like https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/ for adding the header with the token to every call. However, I think you should use a dedicated auth library for this.

Also your store has revision: 11 - that is for an old version I believe.

Comment: I've updated ember to 1.3 and ember data, handlebars to those that come with ember 1.3 the problem is that after I defined the custom adapter for the employees model simply nothing happens so all I was hoping to find is an example that contains using custom RESTAdapter URL for a model (ex. employees) and how to make that customAdapter load data from API by contacting the api and sending token in header. I've checked ajaxPrefilter but I am not sure how this is going to help me especially that ember is not even processing the code for rest adapter

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  setHeaders: function() {
    this.set('headers', { "Token": "0000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000" });
  }.on('init');
});
```

I think you'll need ember-data-1.0.0-beta.x for this to work.

Comment: Tried it but the app is not even calling the API on server...any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Your app is not making any requests to the API? You'll need to fetch something from the API, with something like this in a route: `this.store.find('employee');`