# serialize unconventional JSON with Ember-data

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

my api `api/customers` return:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "CustomerID": "ALFKI",
            "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
            "ContactName": "Maria Anders",
            "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
            "id": "b0d16ed0-c901-4ca3-ba41-7fc74c96909f"
        },
        {
            "CustomerID": "ANATR",
            "CompanyName": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
            "ContactName": "Ana Trujillo",
            "ContactTitle": "Owner",
            "id": "3f8ac226-9f78-42df-b337-0505f69792c3"
        },
        {
            "CustomerID": "ANTON",
            "CompanyName": "Antonio Moreno Taquería",
            "ContactName": "Antonio Moreno",
            "ContactTitle": "Owner",
            "id": "09d31df6-69f4-43e4-9cc6-7faa5b8b5e3b"
        }
    ]
}
```

but ember(`/customers`) should expects:

```
{
    "customers": [
        {
            "CustomerID": "ALFKI",
            "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
            "ContactName": "Maria Anders",
            "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
            "id": "b0d16ed0-c901-4ca3-ba41-7fc74c96909f"
        },
        {
            "CustomerID": "ANATR",
            "CompanyName": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
            "ContactName": "Ana Trujillo",
            "ContactTitle": "Owner",
            "id": "3f8ac226-9f78-42df-b337-0505f69792c3"
        },
        {
            "CustomerID": "ANTON",
            "CompanyName": "Antonio Moreno Taquería",
            "ContactName": "Antonio Moreno",
            "ContactTitle": "Owner",
            "id": "09d31df6-69f4-43e4-9cc6-7faa5b8b5e3b"
        }
    ]
}
```

I find this answer: [GET unconventional JSON with Ember-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699678/get-unconventional-json-with-ember-data)

so I try(in my app/serializers/customers.js):

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  extractArray: function(store, type, payload, id) {
    var newpayload = { customers: payload.value };
    return this._super(store, type, newpayload, id);
  },
});
```

and in the app/routes/customers.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('customer');
  }
});
```

in the app/models/customer.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  CustomerID: DS.attr('string'),
  CompanyName: DS.attr('string'),
  ContactName: DS.attr('string'),
  ContactTitle: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

and in the app/templates/customers.hbs:

```
{{#each}}
    {{CustomerID}}({{ContactName}}
{{/each}}
```

I open the browser, but it's empty, and no error message, so why it doesn't work?

Comment: you might need to use `{{model.CustomerID}}` unless you are using `ObjectController` with is depreciated

Answer (score 2):

Override `typeForRoot` in the serializer:

```
typeForRoot: function(root) {
    if (root === 'value') root = 'customers';
    return this._super(root);
}
```

The problem here is that the "root" key (the top-level key in the JSON, which Ember Data uses to figure out what model this is supposed to be) is wrong, so you need `typeForRoot` to patch that up.

(`extractArray` does something different: it handles array-valued *properties*. Anyway, it won't work to fix up `app/serializers/customers.js` (probably should be `customer.js`) because Ember has no way at this point in time of even knowing that the customer model is involved.)

Comment: Hello, @torazaburo, i read the source code of typeForRoot https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.16.1/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest-serializer.js#L550 It return the singularize name, but i need plural name(I need `customers` not `customer`), so your answer doesn't work.

Comment: Models should have singular names. Since yours doesn't (I suggest you change it to reduce future pain), just return `customers` directly from `typeForRoot` without calling `_super`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way in JavaScript

```
var apiCustomers = {
"value": [
    {
    "CustomerID": "ALFKI",
    "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
    "ContactName": "Maria Anders",
    "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
    "id": "b0d16ed0-c901-4ca3-ba41-7fc74c96909f"
},
{
    "CustomerID": "ANATR",
    "CompanyName": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
    "ContactName": "Ana Trujillo",
    "ContactTitle": "Owner",
    "id": "3f8ac226-9f78-42df-b337-0505f69792c3"
},
{
    "CustomerID": "ANTON",
    "CompanyName": "Antonio Moreno Taquer?a",
    "ContactName": "Antonio Moreno",
    "ContactTitle": "Owner",
    "id": "09d31df6-69f4-43e4-9cc6-7faa5b8b5e3b"
}]
};

var emberCustomers = {"customers": []};

emberCustomers.customers = apiCustomers.value;
console.log(JSON.stringify(emberCustomers));
```

If you are getting your JSON with something like this then here.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
    return Ember.$.getJSON('https://api.github.com/repos/emberjs/ember.js/pulls').then(function(data) {
        var emberCustomers = {"customers": []};
        emberCustomers.customers = data.value;
        return emberCustomers;
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Do this where exactly?

Comment: Much easier to do this in the serializer via the example above

Comment: But now the retrieved data will not be available in the store, for easy use from other parts of you app. So you probably want to do `pushPayload` or the equivalent to get it into the store. At that point, you are duplicating the great majority of work that Ember Data already does for you--issuing the ajax call, and storing the data--but without any of the other things that Ember Data does for you, such as setting headers on the request or supplying the namespace. Far better to simply use Ember Data as it's meant to be used and tell it how to map the root key using `typeForRoot`.

Comment: You are right.  There is a good explanation of this method here [link](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_typeForRoot)